# Create Purchase Order - Line by Line Record to be displayed

Tags: acumatica

In my Sales Order, I have for the same Inventory ID, multiple lines with differant quantities ordered.

When I mark for PO for all item lines and create Purchase Order, I get a sum value of the Quantity in Purchase Order Line.

In order to get multiple lines in Purchase Order as the way they are entered in Sales Order, how to modify and extend the Create Purchase Order code !

Comment: Can anybody throw some light on SOLineSplit Table and INItemPlan ??

Comment: Also POFixedDemand ??

Comment: I am waiting for the Answer here !  Anybody can help me in the Customization here ??

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the Purchase Order report.  The grouping is done on that report.